# Обновление jsp страницы после обработки формы

Tags: jsp

Требуется написать калькулятор с помощью jsp. Должна быть одна страница jsp с формой, содержащей 2 поля ввода и 4 кнопки. После нажатия на одну из кнопок внизу страницы должен выводиться ответ. При этом в полях ввода
должны сохраняться прежние значения.

Создал следующую страницу:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Enumeration" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<%!String answer = "";%>
<%
  String operation;
  String a1 = request.getParameter("atribute1");
  String a2 = request.getParameter("atribute2");
  if(a1 != null && a2 != null) {
    double x = Double.parseDouble(a1);
    double y = Double.parseDouble(a2);
    Enumeration<String> paramNames = request.getAttributeNames();
    String result = a1;
    StringBuffer resultBuffer = new StringBuffer(result);
    while (paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
      operation = paramNames.nextElement();
      switch (operation) {
        case "sum":
          resultBuffer.append(" + ").append(a2).append(" = ").append(x + y);
          answer = resultBuffer.toString();
        case "mul":
          resultBuffer.append(" * ").append(a2).append(" = ").append(x * y);
          answer = resultBuffer.toString();
        case "sub":
          resultBuffer.append(" - ").append(a2).append(" = ").append(x - y);
          answer = resultBuffer.toString();
        case "div":
          resultBuffer.append(" / ").append(a2).append(" = ").append(x / y);
          answer = resultBuffer.toString();
      }
    }
  }
%>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/mystyle1.css"/>
</head>
<body class = stpage>
<h1 class = stpage>Calculator</h1>

<form class="inputform" action="index.jsp" method=post>
  <div style="display: inline-block">
    <label for="argument1" class = inputform>First argument</label>
    <input type="text", id="argument1", name="argument1", required="required", class = inputform1 value="<%=request.getParameter("atribute1")%>"> <!--добавить валуе-->
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block">
    <label for="argument2" class = inputform>Second argument</label>
    <input type="text", id="argument2", name="argument2", required="required", class = inputform2 value="<%=request.getParameter("atribute2")%>">
  </div>
  <button id="sum" name="sum", type="submit", class=inputform>Summation</button>
  <button id="mul" name="mul", type="submit", class=inputform>Multiplication</button>
  <button id="sub" name="sub", type="submit", class=inputform>Subtraction</button>
  <button id="div" name="div", type="submit", class=inputform>Division</button>
</form>

<%=answer%>
</body>
</html>
```

При нажатии на кнопку, ни ответ не появляется, ни значения, введённые в инпуты, не сохраняются.

В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что я перепутал имена текстовых полей в форме. Поля ввода назывались "argument1" и "argument2", а параметры я получал по именам "atribute1" и "atribute2". Ну и информацию о том, какая кнопка была нажата, получаю теперь другим образом.

Кнопки теперь описываются так:

```
  <button name="performButton", type="submit", class=inputform value="sum">Summation</button>
  <button name="performButton", type="submit", class=inputform value="mul">Multiplication</button>
  <button name="performButton", type="submit", class=inputform value="sub">Subtraction</button>
  <button name="performButton", type="submit", class=inputform value="div">Division</button>
```

Информацию о том, какая кнопка была нажата, получаем следующей строкой:

```
operation = request.getParameter("performButton")
```